# Implementing moving object on a dynamic background, Swing (Pacman game)

Tags: java, swing, background, pacman

I am coding a Pacman game and I ran into few problems while trying to implement it.

I have a main `JFrame` which holds the background, and the points on it, the points are added in the `paint()` method.

I added to the frame a `JPanel` that makes the board which Pacman is on, Pacman is being painted by `paintComponent()`.
Pacman movement is decided by a `KeyListener which is on the frame.

The problems I'm running into:

1. If upon pressing a key I call the `paint` function of the frame, which later calls the `paintComponent` method of the panel, my screen is blinking because each time it repaints all of the points.
2. If upon pressing a key I call directly to the panel `paintComponent()` method and paint the Pacman, it stays on the board like in gif number 2.

1: [image]

2: 
[image]

This is the `paint` method of the frame:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 800; j++)
                if (boardPanel.getBoard().getTileXY(i, j).getPill() != null) 
                   g.drawImage(yellowPil, i, j, null);
    boardPanel.paintComponent(g);
}
```

And this is the `paintComponent`:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawImage(pacmanImage,pacman.getX(),pacman.getY(),null);
}
```

this is how i call each of this methods (its in the jframe class) :

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            boardPanel.movePacman(Direction.RIGHT);
            boardPanel.paintComponent(getGraphics()); // this will casue ` 
                                                         problem 2`
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            boardPanel.movePacman(Direction.LEFT);
            repaint(); // this will cause problem 1
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            boardPanel.movePacman(Direction.DOWN);
            repaint();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            boardPanel.movePacman(Direction.UP);
            repaint();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). 3) Based on what's above now, I'd say don't change the paint method of the frame, but instead do all the custom painting from the panel. Never directly call `paint` or `paintComponent` - always simply call `repaint()` on the component or any parent container.

Comment: hey andrew, thanks for the help. i added more code to the thread. i have tried to call panel.repaint() but it didnt change anything at the code. is there any way i can delete all previous "pacman's" that shows up in problem number 2 ?  thank again.

Comment: *"i added more code to the thread."* ... why? And more importantly, did you actually ***read*** the linked advice? Minus one because I think you made a random guess about what an MCVE / SSCCE is, and that is very poor research.